# How to return a number using to_i when the input starts with "$"

Tags: ruby

`to_i` returns 0 whenever the input starts by anything other than an integer. For example, if I input `$32` it returns 0, but if I enter `32`, it returns the number 32. I found another post that said `to_i` only accepts digits, but did not offer an alternative solution.

Is there a way around this? I want the user to be able to input a "$" before their number. As it stands, my code looks like this:

```
puts"What is the cost of a gallon of paint?"

cost=gets.chomp.to_i

total_cost=cost*@gallons_needed"
```

Comment: The work-around is: Don't use `to_i`, or strip a leading `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meditate on these:

```
"$1\n"[1..-1].to_i # => 1
"$1.99\n"[1..-1].to_i # => 1
"$100.99\n"[1..-1].to_i # => 100
```

This breaks down when there's a leading `-`:

```
"-$100.99\n"[1..-1].to_i # => 0
```

That can be fixed using `sub` instead of a slice:

```
"-$100.99\n".sub('$', '').to_i # => -100
```

The problem is, money is not all integers, so `to_i` is probably not really what you want. Instead you should be using `to_f`:

```
"$1\n".sub('$', '').to_f # => 1.0
"$1.99\n".sub('$', '').to_f # => 1.99
"$100.99\n".sub('$', '').to_f # => 100.99
"-$100.99\n".sub('$', '').to_f # => -100.99
"$-100.99\n".sub('$', '').to_f # => -100.99
```

Note: It isn't necessary to use `chomp` to remove the trailing new-line. `to_i` and `to_f` will stop when they see a non-digit:

```
"1\n".to_i # => 1
"1.99\n".to_f # => 1.99

"1 1\n".to_i # => 1
"1.99 2\n".to_f # => 1.99
```

Again, because of this behavior, `"\n"` and `1\n` or `2\n` will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`String.to_i` only parses the leading numeric characters in a string and stops as soon as it hits a non-numeric character. In this case, `$` is non-numeric so you get `0`.

This matches the behavior described in the documentation: [Class: String (Ruby 2.0.0)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i)

To properly parse the value, you'll need to strip the `$` from the start of the input using something like:

```
cost = gets.chomp.sub('$','').to_i
```

Comment: Is there a way around this? Is there another string I can use? For the sake of my program, I would like the user to be able to input a "$" before their number.

Comment: @ColtonHaugrud - Updated.

Comment: For this particular program, this works best and is easiest for me to understand. Thank you.